# How to plug into the play lifecycle with a module instead of a Plugin?

Tags: plugins, module, lifecycle, playframework-2.4

I see the Plugin class is now deprecated (as of 2.4.x version of play)... In the api documentation it says I should use modules instead... so that's my question.
How do I write a module, and how do I plug that module into the play lifecycle of the main app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify which language you're using, so I'll quickly cover both.  I'm basing both answers on the following repositories:

- https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java
- https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala

### Java

1. Write your functionality any way you want - there are no specific classes to extend.  If you have dependencies on Play components such as `Configuration`, you should inject them.

   ```
   @Singleton
   public class MyModuleCode {

       private final boolean enableWidgets;

       @javax.inject.Inject
       public MyModuleCode(final Configuration configuration) {
           this.enableWidgets = configuration.getBoolean("widgets.enabled", false);
       }
   }
   ```

Note that dependency injection is used in place of static reference.  Also, note that I've given this example a `@Singleton` annotation, but it's also possible to have, for example, per-request scope.

See [the Play DI docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection) for more information

2. Expose the components of your module.  To do this, extend the `play.api.inject.Module` class and implement `public Seq<Binding<?>> bindings(final Environment environment, final Configuration configuration)`.

   ```
   package com.example.module;

   public class MyModule extends Module
   {
       @Override
       public Seq<Binding<?>> bindings(final Environment environment,
                                       final Configuration configuration)
       {
           return seq(bind(MyModuleCode.class).toSelf().in(Singleton.class));
       }
   }
   ```

Here, you can also bind implementations to interfaces, configure instance providers and so on.

3. If it's something you're publicly releasing the module, let's assume you do this here - it's out of scope of the question.  Let's also assume you've added a dependency for the module in whichever project you're working on.
4. Enable the module in `application.conf`.

   ```
   play {
       modules {
           enabled += com.example.module.MyModule
       }
   }
   ```
5. The components exposed via your module - just `MyModuleCode` in this example - is now available for injection into your controllers, actions, etc.
6. If you need a shutdown hook, just inject `ApplicationLifecycle` into the component and register the hook; see https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up for details.

### Scala

1. Write your functionality any way you want - there are no specific classes to extend.  If you have dependencies on Play components such as `CacheApi`, you should inject them.

   ```
   @Singleton
   class DefaultPatternCache @Inject() (cache: CacheApi) extends PatternCache {
       override def apply(value: String): Option[Pattern] = cache.getOrElse[Option[Pattern]](key = s"Deadbolt.pattern.$value") { Some(Pattern.compile(value)) }
   }
   ```

Note that dependency injection is used in place of static reference.  Also, note that I've given this example a `@Singleton` annotation, but it's also possible to have, for example, per-request scope.

See [the Play DI docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) for more information

2. Expose the components of your module.  To do this, extend the `play.api.inject.Module` class and implement `def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]]`.

   ```
   package com.example.module

   import com.example.module.cache.{DefaultPatternCache, PatternCache}
   import play.api.inject.{Binding, Module}
   import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}

   class MyModule extends Module {
       override def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration): Seq[Binding[_]] = Seq(bind[PatternCache].to[DefaultPatternCache])
   }
   ```

Here, you can also bind implementations to traits, configure instance providers and so on.

3. If it's something you're publicly releasing the module, let's assume you do this here - it's out of scope of the question.  Let's also assume you've added a dependency for the module in whichever project you're working on.
4. Enable the module in `application.conf`.

   ```
   play {
       modules {
           enabled += com.example.module.MyModule
       }
   }
   ```
5. The components exposed via your module - just `MyModuleCode` in this example - is now available for injection into your controllers, actions, etc.
6. If you need a shutdown hook, just inject `ApplicationLifecycle` into the component and register the hook; see https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up for details.

### Summary

Modules are no longer anything special - they're just a way of grouping injectable components.

Comment: What if I want to register a Jackson json module? where should I do so(without globalsetings)? it's not like I need to inject some instance of some class into my code, i just need to run some code before any http request.

Comment: It's explicitly covered in the documentation: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpRequestHandlers https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers

Comment: I mean, I need to do it before any http request happens, but only once, not one pero request.

Comment: Declare the class containing the code as an eager singleton - it'll run once, when the application starts up.  See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings for details.